# How to differentiate the different possible meanings of "Supporting" a team

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, word-request, comparative-constructions, conversation

Is there not a better, word for "support", when referring to "supporting a team". One sure must be able to differentiate between, supporting financially, supporting the causes the team stands for emotionally from the heart, and whistling at the team because you, in that current state of mind, envision that team representing a separate thing, obviously completely disconnected from whatever that team, in terms of its worldly endeavors, stands for.

These are three separate things, and English sure needs to have a way to differentiate between these things.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You could differentiate them by saying "financial support", "emotional support", and I'm not entirely sure about the third one.

Comment: There are many such terms in English; perhaps you need to do more research. In American English, for instance (to name just one) we _**root for**_ a team. A dedicated fan is sometimes called a _rooter._ "Fan" is a shortening of "fanatic". (We are grateful for your profoundly insightful assessment of the deficiencies in our language and recommendations for its improvement. If it is so inadequate, why do you feel the need to learn it?)

Comment: @PEDant: I think you got is slightly wrong. I cannot see a real complaint (about deficiencies), as much as I see a need to enrich his vocabulary and experience. For what it's worth, he might even be a native English speaker (possibly trying to explain English to a foreigner).

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, there are several ways to ***support*** a team.

The word usually used for spiritual, emotional, and enthusiasm is

> fan

The words used for major financial support, beyond buying a ticket, are

> owner
>   sponsor

The persons who causes trouble for the team or the team supporters are called

> hooligans

Remember:

> You can change your mates,  and you can change your wife,
>   but you can never change your team!

Comment: you provided the words for the different kinds of support**er**s, not for support**ing**. E.g.: what kind of support does a _fan_ provide? etc. From the question: **word for _"support"_**